# Why does Telerik cdn not work in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dojo, telerik, cdn

This is a very stupid and amateur question, but I used Telerik's CDN in my demo website and it works everywhere except IE,
and I wanted to know why this is happening.

I included all the files like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />    
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see I tried doing it like they have done in their dojo examples and I also tried adding 'http://' but still the files don't seem to load in IE and I wanted to know why this happens because everywhere else the code seems to run flawlessly and if I give it a local source it works in IE also, I just wanted to know why CDN are not working in IE, am I missing something very basic ?

the rest of the code is

```
 <%-- Main Body --%>
<form id="form1" >
    <div id="grid"></div>
</form>
<%--End of Main Body --%>
<%-- Scripts --%>
<script>

    var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://localhost:50371/api";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            change: function (e) {
                if (e.action == "itemchange") {
                    if (e.field == "MonthsOfSalary" || e.field == "Salary") {
                        var item = e.items[0];
                        item.trigger("change", { field: "NetSalary" })
                    }
                }

            },
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/CarDetails/GetCarDetails",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET"
                },
                update: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/CarDetails/UpdateCarDetails",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: function (data) {
                        return data.models;
                    }
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/CarDetails/DeleteCarDetails",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: function (data) {
                        return data.models;
                    }
                },
                create: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/CarDetails/AddCarDetails",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: function (data) {
                        return data.models;
                    }
                },

                parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                    if (operation === "update" || operation === "create" || operation === "destroy") {
                        return JSON.stringify(data.models);
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            batch: true,

            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "DetailId",
                    Total: function () {
                        return this.get("MonthsOfSalary") * this.get("Salary");
                    },
                    fields: {
                        "DetailId": { editable: false, type: "number", nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                        "CarsId": { editable: false, type: "number", nullable: false, defaultValue: 1, validation: { required: true } },
                        "FirstName": { type: "string", nullable: false, validation: { required: true, required: { message: "Enter a First Name" } }, defaultValue: "First" },
                        "LastName": { type: "string", nullable: false, validation: { required: true, required: { message: "Enter a Last Name" } }, defaultValue: "Last" },
                        "PhoneNumber": { type: "number", nullable: false, validation: { required: true, min: 1000000000, max: 9999999999, required: { message: "Entera ten digit number" } }, defaultValue: 1111111111 },
                        "Email": { type: "string", nullable: false, validation: { email: true, email: { message: "Enter Email in a@a.com Format" }, required: true, required: { message: "Enter an Email" } }, defaultValue: "e@mail.com" },
                        "MonthsOfSalary": { type: "number", nullable: false, validation: { required: true, min: 1, max: 48, required: { message: "Enter a number between 1 & 48" } }, defaultValue: 1 },
                        "Salary": { type: "number", nullable: false, validation: { required: true, min: 1, max: 10000000, required: { message: "Enter a number between 1 & 1,00,00,000" } }, defaultValue: 1 },
                        "NetSalary": { editable: false, type: "number", nullable: false, validation: { required: true, min: 1, max: 480000000, required: { message: "Enter a number between 1 & 48,00,00,000" } }, defaultValue: 1 },
                        "CarName": { editable: true, type: "string", nullable: false, validation: { required: true }, defaultValue: "Ford" },
                        "CarColor": { editable: false, type: "string", nullable: false, validation: { required: true }, defaultValue: "Red" },
                        "BirthDate": { type: "date", nullable: false, validation: { required: true, required: { message: "Enter a Date" }, min: new Date(1989, 01, 01), max: new Date(), date: { message: "Enter a Valid Date" } }, defaultValue: new Date() },
                        "Car": { nullable: false },
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        $(function () {


            var cars = [];

            $.get(crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Cars/GetCars", function (data, status) {

                cars = data;
            });
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                excel: {
                    fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx",
                    filterable: true
                },
                navigatable: true,
                pageable: false,
                height: 550,
                navigatable: true,
                groupable: true,
                filterable: true,
                columnMenu: true,
                reorderable: false,
                resizable: true,
                sortable: true,
                toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel", "excel"],
                columns: [
                             {
                                 field: "CarName", title: "Car",
                                 editor: function (container, options) {
                                     $('<input data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="Name" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoDropDownList({
                                         dataSource: {
                                             data: cars
                                         },
                                         dataValueField: "Color",
                                         dataTextField: "Name",
                                         autobind: true,
                                     });
                                 }
                             },
                             { title: "First Name", field: "FirstName" },
                             { title: "Last Name", field: "LastName" },
                             { title: "Phone Number", field: "PhoneNumber" },
                             { title: "Email", field: "Email" },
                             { title: "Months", field: "MonthsOfSalary" },
                             { title: "Salary", field: "Salary" },
                             { title: "Net Salary", field: "NetSalary", template: "#=Total() #"},
                             { title: "Joining Date", field: "BirthDate", format: "{0:dd MMM yyyy}" },
                              {
                                  title: "Select",
                                  template: "<input type='checkbox' />"
                              },
                             { command: [{ name: "destroy", text: "" }] }
                ],
                editable: {
                    editable: true,
                    confirmation: true
                },
            });
        });

    });

</script>
<%-- End of Scripts --%>
```

I added the links in `<head>` tag and the code is in `<body>` tag, I removed some extra code for brevity.

Comment: did it worked? and is there any other errors?

Comment: yes it worked wonderfully ! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official telerik website

> Kendo widgets provide a WAI-ARIA support, which means that some
>   ARIA-specific attributes are added to the HTML element. When a widget
>   tries to add an ARIA attribute using jQuery's attr method, which in
>   turn calls the Element.setAttribute method, the Internet Explorer in
>   Compatibility mode will raise a JavaScript error with the following
>   message:
>
> SCRIPT3: Member not found (in Internet Explorer 10+ in Compatibility
>   Mode) The problem is reported to Microsoft on
>   https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/774078. Also there
>   is a jQuery bug report where more information can be found.

**Solution:**

Option 1 - Force the Internet Explorer to use the Edge mode:add this below line in the head section so it makes the browser to use the latest version of internet explorer Edge Mode

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Option 2 - Path jQuery. The bug link is here [Bug Link](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12577)

---

For more information visit here [Official Telerik](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/troubleshoot/troubleshooting-common-issues)